# Updat geodesic distance matrix with additional vertices

Tags: matlab, graph, distance, shortest-path

I have a geodesic ditance matrix computed for a partiuclar undirected graph and would like to update this matrix with some added vertices. Is there any way around to include the vertices without doing the whole computation for the every point?

To be elaborate, I do estimate the adjancy weighted matrix for the added vertices and re-execute the shortest-path algorithm, e.g. Dijkstra's and Floyd-Warshall algorithms. Please correct me if there is something wrong or missing.

Thanks for any clue and advice...

Comment: Why would you need to recompute the distances between all vertices? Can't you just find them for the new vertex and augment the distance matrix accordingly by adding a new row and column to the end of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to compute **all** of the paths again, you can just update the distance matrix with the new vertex.

Let `n` be the new vertex. First you need to compute the distances between each vertex `1..(n-1)` and `n` going through each intermediate vertex `k` (in matlab-ish pseudo-code):

```
//% distance matrix is initially equal to adjacency matrix
distance(n,:) = adjacency(n,:); 
for kk = 1:n-1
   for ii = 1:n-1
      if (distance(ii,kk) + distance(kk,n)) < distance(ii,n)
         distance(ii,n) = distance(ii,kk) + distance(kk,n);
         //% distance(n,ii) = distance(ii,kk) + distance(kk,n); 
         //%   ^^ the above for undirected graphs
         //% also update parent matrix, if used
      end
   end
end
```

Now, use vertex `n` as a new `k` intermediate vertex to update all of the distances between each vertex `1..n-1` and every other vertex. The logic is the same with just an adjustment on which indices we use:

```
for ii = 1:n-2
   for jj = 1:n-1  //% or ii+1:n-1 for undirected graphs
      if (distance(ii,n) + distance(n,jj)) < distance(ii,jj)
         distance(ii,jj) = distance(ii,n) + distance(n,jj)
         //% same notes as above
      end
   end
end
```

As you can see, we're removing one loop from the original Floyd-Warshall algorithm each time, so our time complexity is `O(|V^2|)` rather than `O(|V^3|)` for re-executing the whole algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the detaid reply. It helped a lot. I did the same as you noted for updating the augmented graph with new vertices, but couldn't get the same result when using the full data with Floyd-Warshall. I posted my codes for both updating and creating the geodesic distance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code as @beaker noted.

```
//%% function to update geodesic distance matrix with new adjancy matrix  
function Dgwaug = updateGeoDis(W,Dgw)  
//% W: weighted adjancy matrix  
//% Dgw : current geodesics-distance matrix  

nmX = length(Dgw); //% number of vertices in the current graph  
nmXaug = length(W); //% number of vertices in the augmented graph  
nmXnew = nmXaug - nmX; //% number of new vertices to be included

//% initialize the distance matrix for augmented graph
Dgwaug = W;  
Dgwaug(1:nmX,1:nmX) = Dgw;  

//% compute the distances between each vertex 1..nmX and each added vertex 1..nXnew (j) going through each intermediate vertex (i)
for j=1:nmXnew
   for i=1:nmX  
      Dgwaug(1:nmX,nmX+j) = min(Dgwaug(1:nmX,nmX+j),Dgwaug(1:nmX,i) + repmat(Dgwaug(i,nmX+j),[nmX 1]));
      Dgwaug(nmX+j,:) = transpose(Dgwaug(:,nmX+j));
   end  
end  

//% compute the distances between each vertex 1..nmX and each vertex 1..nmX going through the each intermediate added vertex k
for k=1:nmXnew  
   Dgwaug(1:nmX,1:nmX) = min(Dgwaug(1:nmX,1:nmX),repmat(Dgwaug(1:nmX,nmX+k),[1 nmX])+ repmat(Dgwaug(nmX+k,1:nmX),[nmX 1]));      
end
```

This my code for Floyd-Warshal using the whole data.

```
//%% function to update geodesic distance matrix with new adjancy matrix  
function Dgw = compGeoDis(W)  
//% W: weighted adjancy matrix  

nmX = length(W); //% number of vertices in the graph  

//% initialize the distance matrix for augmented graph  
Dgwaug = W;  

//% compute the distances between each vertex 1..nmX and each vertex 1..nmX going through the each intermediate vertex k
for k=1:nmX 
   Dgw = min(Dgw,repmat(Dgw(:,k),[1 nmX])+ repmat(Dgw(k,:),[nmX 1]));      
end
```